# How to fill nulls in a KDB table column?

Tags: kdb

```
q)t:flip `name`iq!(`Dent``Prefect;98 32 34)

q)t
name    iq
----------
Dent    98
        32
Prefect 34
```

How can I form an a conditional query to act on the column `name`

```
q)select case when name is null then `Empty else name ,iq from t
```

Expected output:

```
name    iq
----------
name    iq
Dent    98
Empty   32
Prefect 34
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional can be used as a method of basing a column on an expression:

```
q)select ?[null name;`Empty;name],iq from t
name    iq
----------
Dent    98
Empty   32
Prefect 34
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use fill ^ to replace the null values

```
q)update `Empty^name from t
name    iq
----------
Dent    98
Empty   32
Prefect 34
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, you can also get this done using the `where` in the `update` statement :

```
q)update name:`Empty from t where null name
name    iq
----------
Dent    98
Empty   32
Prefect 34
```